# Некорректная работа browserSync

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, npm, browsersync

Во время верстки для авторелоада страницы использую browser-sync. Неисправность состоит в том, что при вызове browser-sync через командную строку `browser-sync start --server --files "*.html, css/*.css"` происходит авторелоад только при изменении html-файлов, изменения стилей же фиксируются, но перезагрузки страницы не происходит. Однако когда файл со стилями выносится в корень папки (рядом с html-файлом), то вызов конструкции `browser-sync start --server --files "*.html, *.css"` фиксирует изменения в html и css-файлах, и в обоих случаях релоад выполняется. В чем может быть загвоздка ?

Comment: Скорее всего вы запускаете сервер и говорите ему, наблюдать за файлами в текущей директории. Нужно указать и подпапки.

Answer (score 1):

*browser-sync start --server --files "*.html, *.css" - здесь указано что браузер синк просматривает только файлы лежащие в корне каталога проекта, поменяйте .css на "name of catalog/*.css" - т.е. отследите вложенность файлов*

Comment: А как запустить чтобы Browsersync отслеживал все файлы в каталоге, в том числе и те что вложенные во всех папках внутри?

Comment: Проверь в link правильность прописанных path чтоб не начинались с '/' ещё ньюанс имя - style.css хотя врядли browser только на index.html реагирует остальное пофиг как именованно